# Stop a file download in Python Requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

So far I'm seeing a lot of info on how to download a file with the Requests module, but nothing covering actually cancelling a download.

I'm currently looping through a series of URLs to see if I get a 200 response code or not. If I land on a URL that starts a file download (`r.status_code == 200`), how do I cancel this file download, or better yet: Preventing downloading in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of GET you could use a HEAD request to get header information only.

```
r = requests.head('http://www.example.com')
```

Comment: And you might want to set the `timeout` argument as well.